# How to split string and make a one with respect to parent

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following strings:

```
"Parent1:Child1"
"Parent1:Child2"
"Parent1:Child3"
"Parent1:Child4"

"Parent2:Child1"
"Parent2:Child2"
"Parent2:Child3"
"Parent2:Child4"

"Parent3:Child1"
"Parent3:Child2"
```

Now I want to create strings like:

```
Parent1:Child1,Child2,Child3,Child4
Parent2:Child1,Child2,Child3,Child4
Parent3:Child1,Child2
```

I have tried many approaches but none of them work correctly. Any help?

Comment: Can you show some of the approaches and explain what went wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linq approach

```
string[] input = { "Parent1:Child1", "Parent1:Child2", "Parent1:Child3", "Parent1:Child4",
                   "Parent2:Child1", "Parent2:Child2", "Parent2:Child3", "Parent2:Child4",
                   "Parent3:Child1", "Parent3:Child2"};
```

- first I `Split()` each item by `:`
- then I `GroupBy()` the first part of the split-result ( = "ParentX")
- finally I concartenate each group key with `:` and `Join()` of all childs

code:

```
string[] result = input.Select(x => x.Split(':'))
                       .GroupBy(y => y.First())
                       .Select(y => y.Key + ":" + string.Join(",",y.Select(z => z.Last())))
                       .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to achieve the above result,

```
List<Child> childdren = new List<Child>
            {
                new Child { ParentName ="Parent1", ChildName ="Child1"},
                new Child { ParentName ="Parent1", ChildName ="Child2"},
                new Child { ParentName ="Parent1", ChildName ="Child3"},
                new Child { ParentName ="Parent1", ChildName ="Child4"},

                new Child { ParentName="Parent2", ChildName ="Child1"},
                new Child { ParentName ="Parent2", ChildName ="Child2"},
                new Child { ParentName ="Parent2", ChildName ="Child3"},
                new Child { ParentName ="Parent2", ChildName ="Child4"},

                new Child { ParentName ="Parent3", ChildName ="Child1"},
                new Child { ParentName ="Parent3", ChildName ="Child2"},

            };


            var ChildByParentName = childdren.ToLookup(x => x.ParentName);
            foreach (var item in ChildByParentName)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key); // Print Parent Name

                foreach (var child in ChildByParentName[item.Key])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + child.ChildName + ", "); // Print Child Names
                }
            }
```

Here, I am using ToLookup() to get all matching parents as Key and it's child as value. Please read more about ToLookup [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads)

Output will look like this-

```
Parent1
        Child1,
        Child2,
        Child3,
        Child4,
Parent2
        Child1,
        Child2,
        Child3,
        Child4,
Parent3
        Child1,
        Child2,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split each string by `:`. 
Use `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. Key will contains Parent details and values will contains children

something, more readable and easy to understand

```
    public static void Main()
        {
            string[] input = new string[]
                        { "Parent1:Child1", "Parent1:Child2",
                          "Parent1:Child3", "Parent1:Child4", 
                          "Parent2:Child1", "Parent2:Child2", 
                          "Parent2:Child3", "Parent2:Child4", 
                          "Parent3:Child1","Parent3:Child2"
                        };

            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            foreach(string s1 in input)
            {
                string[] splitted = s1.Split(':');
                List<string> temp = new List<string>();
                if(!dict.ContainsKey(splitted[0]))
                {
                    temp.Add(splitted[1]);
                    dict.Add(splitted[0], temp);
                }
                else
                    dict[splitted[0]].Add(splitted[1]);
            }

            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kv in dict){
                Console.WriteLine(kv.Key+" : "+ string.Join(",",kv.Value));
            }           
        }
```

Proof of concept: [.net Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/areu01)